# How to set up multiple C files to coexist

Tags: c, gcc

How would I set up a structure such that I have methods in

helper.c

main.c

main.h

... how can I include helper.c in my main.c and use the methods built in helper.c?

I am running makefile as:

```
all:
        gcc -o main main.c
        gcc -o helper helper.c



clean: 
        rm -f main
        rm -f helper
```

I understand I need a helper.h, but how do I properly set that up.. say I'd like my helper file to look like this:

```
struct Node{
    struct Node* nxt;
    int x;
};

int isThere(struct Node *head, int value){

    if(head==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    struct Node *tmp=head;

    while(tmp!=NULL){
        if(tmp->x==value){
            return 1;
        }
        tmp=tmp->nxt;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct Node *nodeInsert(struct Node *head, int value){
    if(head==NULL){
        head=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        head->x=value;
        head->nxt=NULL;
        printf("inserted\n");
        return head;
    } else if(head!=NULL && isThere(head,value)==1){
        printf("duplicate\n");
        return head;
    } else{

        struct Node *new;
        struct Node *tmp=head;
        while(tmp->nxt!=NULL){
            tmp=tmp->nxt;
        }   

        new=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        new->x=value;
        tmp->nxt=new;
        new->nxt=NULL;
        printf("inserted\n");
        return head;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -o helper helper.c` would attempt both compilation and linking, but since `helper.c`
doesn't define a `main()`, it won't link.

What you want to do is simply compile `main.c` and `helper.c` separately into object files:

```
gcc -c main.c #-o main.o (the -o main.o part is implied if missing)
gcc -c helper.c #-o helper.o
```

and then link the resulting object files into the final executable.

```
gcc -o main main.o helper.o
```

As for the header: `helper.c` defines `struct Node` and methods `nodeInsert` and `isThere`. In order to use these properly, `main` needs their prototypes, so the standard way to provide them to it would be to define a `helper.h` header:

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H /*header guard to protect against double inclusion*/
struct Node{
    struct Node* nxt;
    int x;
};
int isThere(struct Node *head, int value);
struct Node *nodeInsert(struct Node *head, int value);
#endif
```

and include it at the top of `main.c`:

```
#include "helper.h"
//...
```

(You can also include it in `helper.c`. That should allow the compiler to help you catch possible erroneous 
inconsistencies.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you miss understanding compiling and linking in C.
There is a lot of source to explain this, here is a good one : http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html

what you should do is compile all of them to object files then link them together.
you can do this in single command

`gcc -o executable main.c helper.c`

or compile each one first then link them together

`gcc -c main.c
gcc -c helper.c
gcc -o executable main.o helper.o`

Make sure you write prototypes for all functions of helper.c in helper.h
and include helper.h at the beginning of main.c

Answer (score 1):

Change your makefile so that all the `.c` files that are supposed to be in the binary are referenced:

```
all:
    gcc -o main main.c helper.c
```

Also, your code in `main.c` needs to know the method declarations in `helper.c`, which is why the struct declarations and the function declarations for the code in `helper.c` should be in `main.h` (or in `helper.h` and included in `main.h`)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @John Weldon answer that you can include your `helper.c` in your `main.c` directly and declare functions in it as `static` like this example:

```
// main.c    
#include "helper.c"

int main(void)
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}

// helper.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void HelloWorld(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!!!");
}
```

And in your Makefile you compile helper.c and main.c together like:

```
gcc -o main main.c helper.c
```